# How to create and edit many-to-many join model in Ember.js with Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models with a many-to-many relationship but I have to store a property that belongs to the relationship itself. It's a typical use of a join table so the models are defined as (pseudocode):

```
Module:
    name 'string'
    type 'string'
    modulesProfiles hasMany ModuleProfile

Profile:
    name 'string'
    type 'string'
    modulesProfiles hasMany ModuleProfile

ModuleProfile:
    enabled 'boolean'
    module belongsTo Module
    profile belongsTo Profile
```

There is a full jsbin code example in: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/quwod/4

I have a list of modules and a list of profiles. For each profile I can assign several modules and enable or disable the relation so I can have one module in two profiles with different enabled status.

So, if I want to create/edit a ModuleProfile, what can I do?

In the jsbin there is a route "profile.assign" where I suppose I have to load all the modules and show a list of modules with a checkbox to select wich ones are going to be assigned to the active profile and another checkbox to enable or disable the relation. This is not very hard but...what happens when there are some modules assigned to the profile already? How can I know which ones are already selected and how can I edit them?

I can't see an easy way and I'm a little bit lost. Any ideas?

Thanks and sorry my english :(